# Modifying .css style of google reCaptcha

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm just trying to customize my reCaptcha. Any one please knows of a solution for this. I'm feeling really frustrated with this thing. I tried this but is not working:

```
$('#g-recaptcha').children().css({
    background: transparent,
    border: 0
});
$('#g-recaptcha').children().css({
    border-radius: 0, 
    box-shadow: none,
    -webkit-box-shadow: none,
    -moz-box-shadow: none
});
```

Also tried many example from here and any of them work.

I know doing anything to an iframe can be a pain in the ass. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reCaptcha is an iframe on a different domain so there is no way to reliably style it.